# How to retrieve firebase data and copy it to google sheets?

Tags: android, firebase, google-apps-script, firebase-realtime-database

i'm making an app for my school that collects specific data from firebase real-time database, I am currently following a tutorial (i am really new into google apps script). I tried this code:

```
function getAllData() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g1AELHBONzjEvfMekn3U86xVs9bDdX68bp5i3U2qnjsc)
  var firebaseUrl = "https://example.firebaseio.com/";
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
  var data = base.getData();
  for(var i in data) {
    Logger.log(data[i].logbookId + ' ' + data[i].logbookfullName + ' ' + data[i].logbookEmail + ' ' + data[i].logbookSubject + ' ' + data[i].logbookDate + ' ' + data[i].logbookTime);
  }
}
```

but it seems It doesn't work. Can someone give me a solution?

Comment: What did you do to make FirebaseApp available in your script?  The error message is clearly saying FirebaseApp is not defined.

Comment: then could you please give a correction? I'm really a beginner at apps script and firebase, which i followed a tutorial to make this code.. @DougStevenson

Comment: i dont really get it too @DougStevenson

Comment: Edit your question to say exactly which tutorial you're using.

Comment: changed it @DougStevenson

Comment: I don't see a link to a tutorial in your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native `FirebaseApp` within Google Script. I believe you are trying to use this [Firebase Libray by RomainVialard](https://github.com/RomainVialard/FirebaseApp). First you should follow the [Install Guide](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase) to install the library into your script.

> Add the library key `MYeP8ZEEt1ylVDxS7uyg9plDOcoke7-2l` into Resources menu > Libraries.

You should then be able to use the `FirebaseApp` object and functions.